# Unable to launch android emulator on Mac OS X, fails with image not found error

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, android-virtual-device, dyld

Pre-reqs:
OS: Mac OS X,
Product version: 10.10.5,
Android Studio: 2.2.3 for MAC

Background:
1. Installed android studio in Mac
2. Created a emulator in AVD manager
3. When I launch emulator from terminal, I see below issue

**Output:**

```
mac1deblr:~ root# cd /private/var/root/Library/Android/sdk
mac1deblr:sdk root# emulator -list-avds
Nexus
Pixel
mac1deblr:sdk root# emulator @Pixel    dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/Versions/A/CoreImage
      Referenced from: /private/var/root/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/qt/lib/libQt5WebEngineCoreAndroidEmu.5.12.1.dylib
      Reason: image not found
    Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

**Config details for reference: My env variables in MAC as below**

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export JAVA_HOME;
export ANDROID_HOME=/private/var/root/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/emulator:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin:$PATH
export JASMINE_HOME=/private/var/root/node_modules/.bin/jasmine
export PATH=$JASMINE_HOME:$PATH
```

**Emulator is at**

```
mac1deblr:sdk root# which emulator
/private/var/root/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator
```

Note: If I directly launch from AVD manager table, nothing happens.

Please let me know the possible cause.